# How to fetch data returned by a asynchronous Service in a controller (Java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a controller :

```
@PostMapping("/xyz")
void getThatMessageAndEmail(@RequestBody(Integer z))
{
   String messageToCatch = MG.messageGetter(z);
   System.out.println(functionToConcat(z,messageToCatch));
}
```

And my service messageGetter, which is an asynchronous service:

```
@Service
class MG()
{
    @Async
    String messageGetter(Integer z)
    {
      return "HELLOFRIEND";
    }
}
```

Now, I am unable to catch the message "HELLOFRIEND" in the controller.
How do I catch the message in the controller (messageToCatch variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: [Async methods **must** be `public`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async#the-async-annotation)! ;-)

Then, you have to refactor the return type to `Future<String`/`CompletableFuture<String>`:

```
@Async
public Future<String> messageGetter(Integer z)
// alternatively CompletableFuture<String> ...
{
  // and provide it accordingly:
  return new AsyncResult<String>("HELLOFRIEND");// or CompletableFuture.of("HELLOFRIEND");
}
```

In controller, you'd:

- block async execution until return or exception:

  ```
  String messageToCatch = MG.messageGetter(z).get(); // in both cases..
  ```
- or (do something in the mean time):

  ```
  Future<String> fut = MG.messageGetter(z);
  while (true) {
     if (fut.isDone()) { // done!
        System.out.println(functionToConcat(z, fut.get()));
        break;
     }
     // do something else
  }
  ```